# How to load Eigen Library in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, eigen

I just want to install a package of Eigen library, based on the guidelines, are which presented [here](http://microsolutions.info/2012/11/eigen-linear-algebra-library-with-visual-c-2010.html)

I just add the library within its address, is which:

`F:\pro\eigen-eigen-1306d75b4a21\eigen-eigen-1306d75b4a21\Eigen` in my PC.

But in the end of the process, I have no access to the `#include<Eigen\Eigen>`

Furthermore, I have no access to the `Eigen` namespace...

```
using namespace Eigen;
```

Does anybody have any experience in such stuff?!

Comment: Did you follow all the steps on the page you've linked to? Specifically, *Add Eigen Library to Include Path*?

Comment: @Praetorian: Yes... As a matter of fact, I did that step by step. But the result isn't the thing one might expect and I have no access to the library!

Comment: Then chances are you didn't do it right :) It could be that you added the path in the question to the include path, but you actually need to drop the `Eigen` at the end. Whatever path you include should have an `Eigen` directory that contains a header file named `Eigen`. Also note that the include paths are specific to Platform and Configuration, so make sure you're adding it to the one you're trying to compile.

Comment: @Praetorian: Yeah!!!!! Here is the access!!! But after access to `Eigen`, I should be able to rearrange the `include` address to `#include <Eigen\src\Eigen>`, based on the structure of the files. But Up here, the choice is `#include <Eigen\src>` and no access to the `Eigen` file. Thus, How can I use `Eigen` file?!

Comment: The problem just resolved... The intellisense just sucks to add the `Eigen` fill, automatically.
Thank you very much.